# How do I "get latest version" for TFS in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, rc, tfvc

This might seem like a stupid question but I just installed VS 2015 RC and I cannot for the life of me figure out how I'm supposed to get the latest version from Team Foundation Server now. It seems the option has been removed from all right-mouse context menus, including Check in... and all other other TFS related menu items.

Comment: Which context menu? Solution explorer?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. All of these features were available in the preview, but in the RC, the context menus are all gone. I can connect to TFS, and typing in a file automatically checks it out, but I can't check it in with the context menus, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Exactly what Sam said ^ I'm keeping 2015 CTP 6 for now on my other computer since I do have TFS controls in the right-click menus there.

Comment: MS feedback I found recommended a repair. I'm trying it now.

Answer (score 18):

**You can resolve the issue by running a repair on Visual Studio 2015** (via Add or remove Programs). I had the same TFS menu problems as the original poster as well as 'Chinese' characters in many of my popup menus (in Tools>Options).

Microsoft mentioned on the feedback site that running a repair fixes this and it indeed does seem to work - even though it's a bit daft to have to run a repair minutes after an installation. The repair must do something to clean up those old pieces that the installation doesn't do.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the feedback article?

Comment: This one https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1308421 and this one: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1297121. As I noticed the 'Chinese' characters I was able to follow two paths to a solution.

Comment: I managed to finally fix it by completely uninstalling VS2015, rebooting and installing it again. A repair like you stated would have probably fixed it as well. The problem was that I installed the 2015 RC over the 2015 CTP6 installation. Everything is back to normal now.

Comment: I installed RC over the Preview too, so similar situation. Glad you were able to resolve it!

Comment: As a follow up, is anyone having trouble accessing on premise TFS builds after the repair? I get a "Page Not Found" error.

Comment: I also installed the RC over CTP6. Same problem. A repair resolved indeed the problem. Thanks! (Perhaps somebody can mark this answer as the correct answer?)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The 'get latest version' option was missing from the right-click menu in the Solution Explorer

[image]

and from the right-click menu in the Source Control Explorer

[image]

And (as [Sam mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30175244/575530)) I was seeing odd non-Roman characters in the TFS options

[image]

**[Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30175244/575530) works for me**, but just for completeness sake there is a 'get latest version' icon (a grey clock with a blue arrow pointing down on it) in the Source Control Explorer's menu bar.

[image: get latest icon]

If an item (a folder or a file) is selected in the Source Control Explorer then clicking the icon will retrieve the latest version from TFS recursively. This worked for me even before running repair (though clearly running repair is a better idea!)

Comment: Good update dumbledad. I actually tried this first before the repair and was able to add the tfs items, but they were all disabled. That was when I gave up and tried the repair. I've just had 5 developers here follow the same steps as me (we all have the preview) and all of us had the same experience too.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where "Get Latest version" option was missing when I right click on the project in Solution Explorer view.

**To bind a solution or project to source control**

1. In Visual Studio 2015, open Solution Explorer and select a solution or
   project to bind.
2. On the File menu, click Source Control, the Advanced, and then select Change
   Source Control. You will see below window. And if you notice the last project does not have Server information.

   [image]
3. In the Change Source Control dialog box, click Bind. If you are already connect to server like in my case it will bind the project. Else, click connect, and click bind, and click OK.
4. Once you click ok, you will be shown a CheckOut window like below. Click CheckOut.[image]

Comment: Thank you for that response. It actually helped me, with my specific problem. Unfortunately your answer does not answer the original question. But I am glad I found the answer anyway.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Once you bind your project to the source control by following his steps the options for source control on right click on the solution appear and also any toolbar option or hotkey you have set for source will work too!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to find solution please follow the below steps:

**1.** In the "Team Explorer" window ( If it's not visible, you can open it by clicking on "View" in the menu and selecting "Team Explorer") click on the "Home" icon to go to the Home page and click on "Source Control Explorer."

**2.** In the "Source Control Explorer," navigate to the folder or branch from which you want to get the latest code.

**3.** Right-click on the folder or solution and select "Get Latest Version."

**4.** If you have any pending changes in your local workspace, you might need to check them in or stash them before getting Get Latest Version. This ensures that your changes are not overwritten.

**5.** After getting the latest version, check the "Output" window for any messages or conflicts that might have occurred during the process. Resolve any conflicts if necessary.

**6.** It's a good practice to build and test your solution to ensure that everything is working correctly.